# How to copy a bsoncxx::builder::basic::document to another?

Tags: mongodb, c++11, bson, mongo-cxx-driver

Is there any way to safely copy a bsoncxx document to another.
In following code I am not able to do that

```
class DocClass
{
private:
    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document m_doc;
public:
    bsoncxx::builder::basic::document& copy(bsoncxx::builder::basic::document& obj)
    {
        obj = m_doc; //Not allowed
        //Error C2280   attempting to reference a deleted function
    }
};
```

There should not be any harm to the object even after copy.
Please help.

Thanks,
Shibin

Comment: Something seems a little confused here. The code and question is written as if you want to copy a `bsoncxx::document::value`, but you are passing around `bsoncxx::builder::basic::document`. Those are very different things. Do you really mean to be copying builders?

Comment: yea, I want to copy a builder. [ i found that builder is non copy-able by default] still is there any way to do that?

Comment: So, let me ask the obvious question. *Why* do you want to copy a builder?

Comment: Basically I am doing the mongodb driver upgrade. So in client code  is something like this:













`void GetBasicPropertiesToFetch(const wstring& collectionName, CMongoBsonBuilder &bsonFieldsToReturn)
{
 //need to copy the class member (builder ) to bsonFieldsToReturn
}`






CMongoBsonBuilder  is wrapper class  which used BSONObjBuilder. Now instead of BSONObjBuilder, using bsoncxx::builder::basic::document.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to copy a bsoncxx::document::value, you can construct a new one from its view:

```
bsoncxx::document::value foo = ...;
bsoncxx::document::value bar{foo.view()};
```

bsoncxx::builder::basic::document is only movable, not copyable. However, you can get view to the underlying document from the builder with the `view()` method, which might be able to help you depending on your use cases. You'll still only be able to `extract` from the builder once though, so you'll have to rely on constructing a second `document::value` if you need more than one.